# How to silence a notebook the second-most radical way? Performance does not matter

Tags: linux, laptop, fan

This sounds like a rather general question,
but I did not find specific advice if one is eager to sacrifice performance for this task.

The case:
I am writing a thesis,
and I need complete silence for this task,
but no 'performant' computer after all.

Some time ago I bought a Lenovo X100e (I liked the keyboard),
installed Arch Linux,
just to notice the fan is always on.

I lowered the cpu frequency (using different tools),
ultimately to find out that this does not matter much for heat reduction.
Google tells me to clean the fan from dust and to kill tasks in Windows,
but I experienced this behaviour on day one running custom build Arch with no X after all ;)

So I bought an ARM chromebook and I am happy with it.

Yet, I want to silence this thing. 
I am not only ready to sacrifice performance,
but the whole device in terms of trying to silence it at last.

I could rip out the fan, but I guess this is too radical to produce a long-term solution.
What is the second-most radical thing I could do to it?

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fan_Speed_Control ?

Comment: Sounds like an awful idea. Is a small CPU fan really so awful? Perhaps ear plugs would be a sufficient alternative?

Comment: Well, if you are willing to sacrifice "the whole device", how about turning it off!!

Answer (score 1):

I did it the radical way and unplugged the fan of my notebook (HP Probook 4720s with Windows7), and installed speedfan to have the temperature in view.

I can work with it for usually about an hour or more, then, at about 80 degree CPU temp, it needs a break for cooling down.

At about 85 degree the notebook itself interrupts working.

I could live with this for about half a year now, consequently skipping videos, Flash etc.

Critical are long backups or copy actions. For these I got an external fan board to put underneath.

Now in summer the surrounding temperature rises and its getting more difficult to live without the fan.

I did this experiment, as the notebook was "old enough" so in case I would buy a new one, and because the programs I use on it have good automatic backup features.

Answer (score 0):

If your motherboard supports ACPI calls and fan monitoring you should be able to set the fan to manual and set its power to 0, therefore disabling it.

Use lm_sensors and watch over the /sys/devices/platform kernel structure to see if you have fan*_input and fan*_manual nodes.